# Make UIDatePicker display only time when clicking UITextfield

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I want to, when I click on my UITextfield, make a UIDatePicker pop up, but I only want it to display time, not dates. What I have done so far

```
-(void)updateTextField:(id)sender
{
    UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)self.myTextField.inputView;
    self.myTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",picker.date];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.myTextField setInputView:datePicker];
}
```

When I then try this in the simulator, this comes up, something I do not want:
http://prntscr.com/47rddt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display only the time when the date is printed in the text field, use a date formatter instead of printing the whole date object.

```
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
self.myTextField.text = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:picker.date];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are four date picker mode available. You can set mode according to your requirement.

```
1) UIDatePickerModeTime
2) UIDatePickerModeDate
3) UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime
4) UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer
```

Set the `datePickerMode` to `UIDatePickerModeTime`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.myTextField setInputView:datePicker];
}
```

**UPDATE**

Used the below code when you set the time in your textfield.

```
-(void)updateTextField:(UIDatePicker *)dtPicker{
    NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    self.myTextField.text = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:dtPicker.date];
}
```

Comment: I have edited my code, so it now looks like this:  UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.myTextField setInputView:datePicker];
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; BUT it still looks the same when clicking the textfield.